# What does "soft-matching of local features" mean?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I read in a paper in which local features (e.g. SIFT,SURF, etc) can be matched to visual vocabulary using soft-matching.

1. What is the meaning of soft-matching here? Is it like how much is the probability of matching two features?
2. How to match a SIFT feature with a quantized (features' descriptors) visual vocabulary?

I really appreciate if you know, please let me know how can I do this in `cv2` and `python`? If there are some resources (codes or tutorial), please share the links.

Comment: You would ease our task by providing the reference. What I can imagine is that the tentative matchings are qualified by a weighting score that rates the plausibility, rather than a sharp match/not match decision.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for your comment. This is [the link of reference](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5255/490925aa1e01ac0b9a55e93ec8c82efc07b7.pdf), section 11.4.2.

Comment: As I said, the matches are weighted by a probability score in the voting process.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you very much for your help, Is there any code that I can learn this procedure step by step?

Comment: Not at all. This is a general concept for use in different situations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you very much once again